# Is there a way to capture a value above and below a specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this especific DataFrame (which is all in one column);

`data={'Name':['10000','Votes','12','10100', 'Votes', '13']}`

`df=pd.DataFrame(data)`
[image]

I want to create two new columns based on the value of the "votes" row.

In the first column, whenever "votes" appears, I want to create a column above the party numbers.

And in the second column, whenever "votes" appears, I'll take the values below. How i could do that in Pandas?

[image: Actual vs Expected DataFrame]

**UPDATE**: Managed to get it done with the code below:

`df['votos'] = np.where(df['col1']=='Votação', df['col1'].shift(-1),np.nan)`

`df['num_candidato'] = np.where(df['col1']=='Votação',df['col1'].shift(1),np.nan)`

Comment: How do you generate this data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Heres one way using [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), but it might not catch all of the edge cases

```
is_votes = df.Name=="Votes"

pd.DataFrame({'Name':df.loc[np.roll(is_votes,-1),"Name"].values , 'Votes':df.loc[np.roll(is_votes,1),"Name"].values})
 
#    Name Votes
#0  10000    12
#  10100    13
```

Comment: Thank! I managed to get it done in this way too:

`df['Votes'] = np.where(df['col1']=='Votes', df['col1'].shift(-1),np.nan)`


`df['Name'] = np.where(df['col1']=='Votes', df['col1'].shift(1),np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how this is implemented, I can only give the "boilerplate" code at best.

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['10000','Votes','12','10100', 'Votes', '13']}

Name = [data["Name"][i] for i in range(0,len(data["Name"]),3)]
Votes = [data["Name"][i] for i in range(2,len(data["Name"]),3)]

newData = {
  "Name": Name,
  "Votes": Votes
}

df = pd.DataFrame(newData)

print(df)
```

You would probably have to change this code around to work with your use case, but this is what I gathered from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on indexing and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[0:len(df):3].reset_index(drop=True), df['Name'].rename(
    'Votes').iloc[2:len(df):3].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Name Votes
0  10000    12
1  10100    13
```